# Arduino Hardware serial library with rts/cts flow control support

Tags: arduino-mega, uart

Does there exist (any user developed etc.) version of the Hardware UART serial library that has support for RTS/CTS based flow control? 
More interested in the Tx side (Arduino sends data, while the peripheral can back-pressure). The library should enable the Arduino to stop transmitting within 1 character of seeing a 'not ready' indication from the peripheral.

Thank you.

Comment: This library may help for the AVR-based Arduinos: https://github.com/i-am-bigmike/HardwareSerial_flow_control

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any such library. You could try to implement one
yourself, and maybe share it with the community. :-)

If you take this route, you will have to copy the file
[HardwareSerial.cpp from the Arduino core](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/1.6.23/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.cpp), make your
changes there, and have your version replace the one from the core. Here
are some ideas that may help to get you started:

- Wire the 'ready' signal from the device to an interrupt-capable pin of
  the Arduino.
- Inside the interrupt handler:

  - when 'ready' is deasserted, disable the UDRE interrupt by issuing
    `cbi(*_ucsrb, UDRIE0)`
  - when ready is asserted, enable it again, but only if the output
    buffer is not empty:
    `if (_tx_buffer_head != _tx_buffer_tail) sbi(*_ucsrb, UDRIE0);`
- Patch `HardwareSerial::write()` to enable the interrupt only if
  'ready' is asserted.
- Note that the UDRE IRQ can be explicitly called
  [by `HardwareSerial::flush()`](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/1.6.23/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.cpp#L219)
  and [by `HardwareSerial::write()`](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/1.6.23/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.cpp#L262) if interrupts are globally
  disabled. You will have to condition this on the 'ready' signal.
- Note also that [`HardwareSerial::write()` can write directly to the
  UART](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/1.6.23/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.cpp#L242) if the buffer is empty. This also has to be
  conditioned on the 'ready' signal.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that CTS would be fairly easy to implement:

```
void loop() {
  uint8_t clear_to_send = digitalRead(CTS);
  volatile char data;
  if (clear_to_send) {
    Serial.write(data);
  }
}
```

I'm not sure about RTS.

Comment: This wont work to stop the transmission within a one (or even a few) characters, because although you stopped the Serial.write, there may already be data in the serial buffer (default 64bytes I think in Arduino lib) that could continue to go out (and potentially lost).
Anyways, I shifted to Teensy, which has hardware based RTS/CTS flow control, so it is capable of stopping as soon as (i believe 1 character) CTS is deasserted

Comment: Hardware USART is better for sure. Though, you could flush the buffer [Serial.flush()](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Flush) after every write and    store the last sent byte to be sent later.

Comment: I'd be surprised if there is no Arduino implementation. Usually, the (hardware) send buffer on an UNO is, I believe, 1 byte. The Arduino serial wrapper has it's own software buffer implemented. You could change it there. But you may have to retrigger the sending manually (since I think they use the "tx complete interrupt" to wait for the next possible send, which won't happen if you stop the sending)

Answer (score 0):

I have I discovered that RTS/CTS may be implemented in genuine Arduinos, but is not supported by Arduinos that use the CH340 USB to serial chip. I found this when my JAVA program could talk with a genuine Uno ok, but didn't send any data to several Arduino compatibles that use the CH340 chip (but did receive from them). I had RTS/CTS set on the JAVA program. When I changed it to FLOWCONTROL_NONE it started working just fine.